# Using .live() to make jQuery plugin affect new element added via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I am building a stream (similar to Facebook wall) that inserts new posts via Ajax.

I also use the jQuery plugin Linkify to transform any link strings into a clickable element.

When a user enters a link, the post is immediately shown on the page (via Ajax) but Linkify does not affect is since it wasn't in the DOM to begin with. When I reload the page, the link is then clickable.

Is there a way of using `.live()` to make a plugin affect future DOM elements added by ajax?

Some code:

```
//-------------Linkify

$('.main_container').linkify();

//-------------stream page structure

<div class="main_container">
    <div class="posts_insert">
         // target to be replaced via ajax
    </div>
    <div class="posts">
         // text of post #1
    </div>
    <div class="posts">
         // text of post #2
    </div>
    <div class="posts">
         // text of post #3
    </div>
</div>

//----------post structure, will replace .posts_insert above

<div class="posts_insert">
     // text of post #1
</div>
<div class="posts">
     // html
</div>
```

Comment: Which linkify plugin are you using?  This https://github.com/uudashr/jquery-linkify  or https://github.com/errumm/Linkify or http://code.google.com/p/jquery-linkify/  :)

Comment: this one: http://github.com/maranomynet/linkify/ -- works very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert the line `$('.main_container').linkify();` into the success function of your ajax call...

eg:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(result){
    //Your functions here
    $('.main_container').linkify();
  }
});
```

This makes sure the linkify function is called AFTER new content is added to the page, affecting new posts :)

** **EDIT**: just clarifying, linkify should be called twice, once on page load and then once on ajax success :)

Answer (score 1):

no, .live() is for attaching event handlers.  you will need to process new data in your ajax success handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade [linkify source code](http://jquery-linkify.googlecode.com/files/jquery.linkify.1.0.0.js) itself and use `.live()` instead of `.click()` and other event binding used in linkify. There is few code change needed. Just like this one:

Line 239:
`$(this).click(function()...` ==> `$(this).live('click', function()...`